# Find elements with same attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this code:

```
     <root>
        <profil>
            <e a="2" id="1">1</e>
            <m a="7" id="2">1</m>
            <e a="4" id="3">1</e>
            <m a="5" id="4">1</m>
        </profil>
        <profil>
            <e a="5" id="5">1</e>
            <m a="3" id="6">1</m>
            <e a="4" id="7">1</e>
            <m a="4" id="8">1</m>
        </profil>
        <profil>
            <e a="7" id="9">1</e>
            <m a="7" id="10">1</m>
            <e a="4" id="11">1</e>
            <m a="2" id="12">1</m>
        </profil>
    </root>
```

I want to have loop for-each m which has same "a" attribute value as e

```
        2- m[id=12]
        4- m[id=8]
        5- m[id=4]
        7- m[id=2]
        7- m[id=10]
```

I tried this but it doesn't work (XSLT 1.0)

```
    <xsl:for-each select="./m/@name=./a/@name">
```

I did it with this

```
    <xsl:for-each select="./m[@name=./a/@name]">
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid. The opening tags do not match the closing tags.

Comment: thnx, this is testing XML for here :)

Comment: If your edit means that you've found the solution it's better to write it as an actual answer instead.